# How to get the ip and port of the docker host in a docker container?

Tags: networking, port, docker

When a docker container is starting, its explosed port would be mapped to a port of the docker host.

Of cause, I can use the specified mapped port, but, I don't want to do so.

Is there a method to get the ip and port of the docker host in a docker container when it is starting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the ip address of the docker host from inside a docker container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: Why not use the mapped port? That is how Docker is supposed work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get it is through `ifconfig` (interface docker0) from the host

From inside a docker, the following command from a docker:

`ip -4 route show default | cut -d" " -f3`