# Insert Docker parent host ip into container's hosts file

Tags: docker

I'm new to Docker and trying to understand what is the best way to insert docker parent host ip into container hosts file.

I'm using the following command in my Dockerfile

`RUN /sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print  $3,"\tdockerhost" }' >> /etc/hosts`

but sometimes hosts ip get change so its non relevant anymore...

The reason to do that, if you ask yourself, is that i need to access another 2 dockers containers (and link not offer this feature).

Thanks,

Comment: I need docker host's ip to be in /etc/hosts file.

Comment: The problem is not with awk, it is with running the command at the wrong time.  Kind of like compile-time vs run-time.

Comment: Linking is the way to achieve it, it is meant to give access to other docker containers. Explain your use case better and how linking does not work for you.

Answer (score 13):

The `--add-host` option is made for this.  So, in your [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) command, do something like:

```
docker run --add-host dockerhost:`/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print  $3}'` [my container]
```

Comment: Are you sure that arg will be valid also after reboot when host ip getting change? it looks like it valid only for creation...

Comment: Ah, you mean if you let Docker restart your containers on reboot?  Yes, that would be a problem. You can restart things differently - see https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/. If you want a dynamic scheme to resolve an address, maybe use DNS?

Comment: The command `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print  $3}'` runs in docker host, instead of in docker container, which produces the wrong ip result.

Comment: @santiago this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to use this with Docker compose's [`extra_hosts:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/extra-hosts) configuration?

Answer (score 5):

`--add-host` option can be used when you create/run your container but since `/sbin/ip` command isn't available in operating systems like OSX, we can use a more generic solution: 
`` docker run --add-host=dockerhost:`docker network inspect \
   --format='{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' bridge` [IMAGE] ``