# How do I wget localhost url's from inside a ubuntu container?

Tags: selenium, docker, localhost

I have a ubuntu container running but I cannot wget the localhost that is running my docker image.

For example, I use a lenovo laptop that runs docker. I then log into my laptop to start and run a ubuntu container. When I ssh into the ubuntu container I am not able to wget localhost url's. Is there a way to connect containers to localhost? Also how many ways can you connect to localhost via a docker container.

This is the error message I get when I wget

```
root@090cdf22ac53:/openchain# wget 127.0.0.1:8090
converted 'http://127.0.0.1:8090' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 
'http://127.0.0.1:8090' (UTF-8)
--2017-09-01 04:41:22--  http://127.0.0.1:8090/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8090... failed: Connection refused.
```

Thanks in advance, all the questions similar to this do not answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Docker for mac [recently gained a docker.for.mac.localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45002996/6309) (17.06).

But for Windows, you might try some of the options detailed in "[How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22944631/6309)", that is at least:

```
 run --env <key>=<value>
```

Passing the IP when running your container is one simple way.

```
 run -e "DOCKER_HOST=$(ip -4 addr show docker0 | grep -Po 'inet \K[\d.]+')"
```

Or, from "[Insert Docker parent host ip into container's hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44956596/6309)"

```
docker run --add-host=dockerhost:`docker network inspect \
--format='{{range .IPAM.Config}}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' bridge` [IMAGE]
```