# Cant' connect to remote DB with docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, coldfusion

I am running a docker container running cf2016. I am using `https://hub.docker.com/r/accent/coldfusion2016/` for my container image.

I am trying to connect to my datasource which is a sqlserver db running on a remote server. The server only allows ip's from within our work network. My docker container can't connect to the remove server as the connection times out. I have tested the connection for my local machine and it work just not via the docker container.

Is docker using a different outgoing IP to connect to the remote network? Shouldn't it just be using my wifi network for sending request to the server?

I am new to docker so a lot of this still doesn't make sense and I can't find the documentation for docker to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'  - This command gives the IP address of the Docker host

Comment: I'm not trying to run a sqlserver container. I want to connect to an already existing instance on a remote server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367100/connect-to-remote-mysql-db-from-docker-container  . I guess this would help.