# Docker connect host mysql for django

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I am trying to connect to my host mysql from docker container but I don't know how to connect.
I have a django project for that I followed [Django Docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#define-the-project-components) I am using this tutorial this one is working fine for djnago and postgres.

I am using mac and I am using mamp server I want to connect my djnago app to my host mysql.

My docker file code is:

```
    FROM python:3
    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    RUN mkdir /code
    WORKDIR /code
    ADD requirements.txt /code/
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    ADD . /code/
```

And my docker compose file is:

```
 version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This one is working fine but I am trying to connect my django app to my host mysql.

I don't know how to connect host mysql from my docker.

Comment: I am asking different question I followed tutorial and it is working my I want to connect this docker to my host mysql.

Comment: may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367100/connect-to-remote-mysql-db-from-docker-container

Comment: You just need to change the name db to your host ip address.

Comment: That is the issue I added my host ip it needs some configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access host database from a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056522/access-host-database-from-a-docker-container)

Answer (score 2):

first with bellow command create a network named `hostnetwork` to have fixed host ip inside containers

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 hostnetwork
```

then change your docker-compose config to connect your containers to `hostnetwork`

```
services:
    db:
        image: image_name
        networks:
            - hostnetwork
networks:
    hostnetwork:
        external: true
```

now you can set django admin db config to your host mysql engine like bellow sample:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '192.168.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "host.docker.internal" host if you are using mac.
But this is only for development in your machine only