# Connect to a mysql server running in a docker container from another container?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have two containers; a node.js server, and a mysql server ...

Both are running fine, I'm trying to connect to the database running in the MySQL container from my node app.

I've created a bridge network:

```
$ docker network create -d bridge mynetwork
```

and run both of my containers in this network with:

```
$ docker run -p 32031:3306 --network mynetwork  --name mysql  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:5.7

$ docker run -p 3000:3000 --network mynetwork  node-server node index.js
```

I'm trying to connect with the IP of the mysql container that I found with `docker inspect mysql`, which is `172.18.0.2` and port `32031`.

Where did it go wrong, it's not connecting?

Comment: Can you write the results of **docker stats** when both containers are up?

Do you expose 32031 port in dockerfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh, my good luck.

It's working now. I rebuilt the docker image and connected to the database with the IP that I found with `inspect mysql` container, and with port `32031`.

Run docker container same as: `$ docker run -p 3000:3000 --network mynetwork  node-server node index.js`

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 3,
  host            : '172.18.0.1',
  user            : 'root',
  port            :  32031,
  password        : 'abc123',
  database        : 'mydatabase',
  charset         : 'utf8mb4',
  timezone        : 'PKT',
  timeout         : 4000
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you connect by IP which you get from `docker inspect command`. That mean your connection now is `172.18.0.2` and port still `3306`

Another way to connect from nodejs (nodejs and mysql in same network). Connect information is:

```
hostname: mysql // container name
port: 3306
```

Comment: That IP address will change whenever the container gets recreated; I'd recommend _never_ looking up or using the container-internal IP addresses.  The host name approach is much more reliable.

Comment: That right, host name by container name is the right way. And thay how docker-compose use

Answer (score 3):

Docker containers connected via a network can communicate internally. Your mysql container is running on port `3306` internally and `32031` externally.

Try connecting via port `3306`. It should work.