# Connecting local cassandra cluster with docker container

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose

I have set of microservices running as docker container. One microservice say A wants to connect to cassnadra running locally on my laptop. in order to do so i have below configurations

snippet from yaml file of service A

```
cassandra:
    hosts: [127.0.0.1]     
    keyspace: "My keyspace"
    protocol_version: 3
    ports: 9042
```

In other side i ran cassandra by calling ./bin/cassandra . and then i connected to cqlsh locally whose output is as below

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.6 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
```

now  when my container comes up and try to connect to this running cassandra hosted on my machine it says as says connection refused . please see the trace below

```
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2076, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal (cassandra/cluster.c:36914)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
[start] application exit with code 1, killing container
```

more info
I am using apache-cassandra-3.0.6.

Please advise.  Thanks

Comment: How are you running docker-daemon in your local environment? If you are using Oracle virtual box or docker machine, can you ssh into the machine and check whether you can access the cassandra service?

Answer (score 2):

As Shibashis has mentioned, probably you cannot reach the host via docker container with `127.0.0.1`

Please find the IP represented as HOST.
[How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container)

Start the cassandra instance by changing the `conf\cassandra.yaml`

- listen_address
- rpc_address

to the recongnized HOST IP.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes this looks good to me . let me try this out i will update again