# On Docker for Mac what would be the host ip as seen from the container?

Tags: macos, docker

I need to setup a debugger on my container, that requires me to set the remote (docker host) IP. In different tutorials I find different IP addresses listed as possible solution. In my container I ran a webserver that showed me that connections made to the container from my host machine come from `172.19.0.1`. This is on Docker for Mac version `1.11.x`.

But how would I reliably find out the host IP as seen from the container on Docker for Mac? When would it be possible for this IP to change?

**Edit:
Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716645/6309**

Comment: @VonC it is not a duplicate as this question concerns "Docker for Mac" which has some important difference in the archtecture

Comment: can you precise where is the listening service and where is the client initiating connection (on mac host or inside the container)? 
to connect from the container to mac host its enough to use the main mac host ip which is usually the `en0`. For the opposite direction looks like currently the only way is to use the usual docker port mapping like `-p 1234:1234`

Answer (score 10):

You can get the ip of the host from within the container by running this command:

```
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

Comment: I get the IP address, but I'm unable to connect to it from the container...

Comment: It must the way you connect to the ip then?

Comment: Check if a network route is available from your container network (aka docker0) and your host machine, probably not :/

Comment: what exactly is this command doing?

Comment: As of Docker 17.06 you can use **docker.for.mac.localhost** which should resolve to the correct host ip

Comment: This last comment here should be the accepted answer. As @ciekawy has mentioned, this is not a duplicate, because it concerns docker for mac.