# Accessing services on the Docker host

Tags: docker

If I start a docker container, I can for some reason access the docker host's services if I use the host's LAN ip, eg:

```
docker run -it ubuntu sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat && nc -z 192.168.196.135 3449"
```

But how do I know which IP to access the host on? Running `ifconfig` doesn't show any networks in the `192.x` range. What if the host is disconnected from the LAN?

Comment: Seems I can normally get it using `docker-machine ip`, but docker-machine doesn't work when using Docker for Mac.

Comment: What about `pinata list` that I mentioned this morning in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38178195/6309? Or (other option) http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716645/6309?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a entry to your container's `/etc/hosts`

```
docker run --add-host="dockerhost:192.168.196.135" -it ubuntu sh -c "apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat && nc -z dockerhost 3449"
```

You also can use this [docker discovery agent](https://github.com/npalm/docker-discovery-agent)

If you need something more sophisticated then that you'll need a service discovery system like [zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/).