# Host unreachable inside Docker container

Tags: curl, docker

I've got a docker container on host `183.83.83.83`
The A record of a subdomain mycontainer.example.com points to this IP.

A curl to `183.83.83.83` or `mycontainer.example.com` gives HTTP status 200 and the correct website.

However the same curl from inside every container on that host (to both the IP or hostname above) fails to connect:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mycontainer.example.com port 80: Host is unreachable
```

This doesn't happen when trying this from a Docker container from another host or from the host itself.

What is going wrong here?

*EDIT:* More details:
The host runs an [Nginx-proxy container](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) which proxies all requests to `mycontainer.example.com` to my frontend container (running a React application through a little node webserver). The frontend container is supposed to proxy all API requests from `mycontainer.example.com/api` to `mycontainer.example.com:1337/api/v1`. However it can't proxy the API requests because I get the error `Host is unreachable` from inside all containers running on this host.

Comment: From your container, can you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716645/6309 and try and curl the result of that command?

Comment: The result is `172.17.0.1`

Comment: That is the bridge IP address. Maybe you could use the --host instead as I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38178195/6309?

Comment: I need to be able to access it via its public IP. I described the problem more in detail in my question.

Comment: I was able to solve it by proxying to the container name instead of the public hostname (using Rancher).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know it is an old question but for anybody coming here, the solution, at least on Linux, is to allow incoming network packets to host from docker bridge network by modifying the `iptables` of the host as following:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

It translates to accept all incoming network packets on host from docker bridge network (assuming it is docker0) i.e. traffic from docker containers.

Here are the details:

```
-I INPUT means to insert a netfilter rule for incoming packets to host
-i docker0 means packets from docker0 interface of the host
-j ACCEPT means accept all packets since a protocol is not defined it implies that packets of any protocol are welcome.
```

Refer to `iptables --help` and [netfilter](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/iptables/index.html) website for more details.

Answer (score 11):

The more current approach of using FirewallD would be to execute the following commands:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 32 switched the backend for the firewall from iptables to nftables. I didn't find how to fix things with nftables, however I found how to switch back to iptables.

While the following commands don't look like best practice, they work for me.

```
sudo sed -i 's/FirewallBackend=nftables/FirewallBackend=iptables/g' /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf
sudo systemctl restart firewalld docker
```

Source: https://dev.to/ozorest/fedora-32-how-to-solve-docker-internal-network-issue-22me

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
if command -v firewall-cmd > /dev/null; then
  NIC=$(ip addr | grep {{docker.network.host.ip}} | awk '{ print $7 }')
  echo "Trusting NIC \"${NIC}\"..."

     sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=${NIC} \
  && sudo firewall-cmd --reload \
  && sudo systemctl restart firewalld \
  || exit $?
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue trying to change a docker-compose network, to fix I deleted all unused networks.

`docker network ls` <- this will list you networks

DO NOT DELETE THOSE:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                DRIVER    SCOPE
970599083e1f   bridge              bridge    local
dddff9d5ec3e   host                host      local
15a80e0436c2   none                null      local
```

`docker network rm <ID|NAME>` <- this will delete a network

Comment: `docker network prune` "deletes all custom networks not used by at least one container".