# how to communicate from a docker container to a docker-machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, docker, docker-machine

My question is how to be able to connect to the docker-machine socket, inside a docker container ?

what i want to achieve is to dockerize an api-gateway, but this api-gateway needs to communicate to the docker-machine socket, to be able to discover the running container like the following:

```
const machine = process.env.DOCKER_HOST
const tls = process.env.DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
const certDir = process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH

if (!machine) {
  throw new Error('You must set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable')
}
if (tls === 1) {
  throw new Error('When using DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 you must specify the property DOCKER_CERT_PATH for certificates')
}
if (!certDir) {
  throw new Error('You must set the DOCKER_CERT_PATH environment variable')
}

const dockerSettings = {
  protocol: 'https',
  host: machine.substr(machine.indexOf(':', 0) + 3, machine.indexOf(':', 6) - 6),
  port: parseInt(machine.substr(-4), 10),
  checkServerIdentity: false,
  ca: fs.readFileSync(certDir + '/ca.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(certDir + '/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync(certDir + '/key.pem'),
  version: 'v1.25'
}
```

This run on localhost, and has access to the env variables and has access to the docker-machine socket.

How i communicate is from the libarary `dockerode` like the following

```
const docker = new Docker(dockerSettings)
```

But once i put it in a container a need to share this socket with the container to be able to execute the docker commands, this is for making a kind of docker service discovery in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

As i wrote in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168409/connect-docker-container-to-local-workbench-mysql-db/42185337#42185337), you can set gateway when starting your container, create some kind of proxy to access you node.js apps or take the host ip from container.

Also, I'd take a look on the dedicated tools to handle docker containers discovery, like [consul](https://hub.docker.com/_/consul/).