# How to connect local kafka in docker container?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka server in my local host, and i want to connect it in my docker container.

I had searched how to connect local services in docker container and i found this: [how-to-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556301/how-to-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-docker)

But it didn't work. Please help me, thanks~

Comment: have a look at https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/

Comment: Attention!!! I want to connect to my local host kafka brokers not in another docker container.

Comment: I do not u nderstand when you say 
"I have a kafka server in my local host, and i want to connect it in my docker container."

Comment: please, clarify - what is run on container? does Kafka running on your local host, and you have another app running inside the docker on same host?

Comment: @evgenyl  yes, the docker container also running in my local host  and i want my app running in the docker container could connect to the kafka that running in my local host.

Answer (score 3):

Try updating kafka config as shown below

```
$ nano config/server.properties
```

uncomment listeners and paste the following

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<local-ip>:9092
```

save file & restart kafka.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui/discussions/1081

In my Kafka server.properties I had advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092. This only allow access via localhost. Once I changed it to my machine's IP address everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you question can be re-phrased as "How can I access my host machine withing my docker container".

As i wrote in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168409/connect-docker-container-to-local-workbench-mysql-db/42185337#42185337), you can set gateway when starting your container, create some kind of proxy to access your Kafka or take the host ip from container.