# Docker host IP inside java program running in the container

Tags: java, docker

is it possible to get the docker host IP inside the java program running in the docker container?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @JeroenHeier The question sounds a bit like an X-Y problem, but other than that I don't think there is anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding that docket from it’s initial design is to isolate the host from containers. Although this is doable, such as passing in a env variable to the container at startup, it is not a good practice. Try to containerize everything, and use a network and network links instead. [Docker Compose maybe helpful]

If you really need to do so for whatever reason here is a link for reference

[How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container)