# How to I get the host address using dockerpy of container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I am trying to figureout from where to get the hostname of a running docker container that was started using **docker-py**.

Based on presence of DOCKER_HOST= file the started docker container my be on a remove machine and not on the localhost (machine running docker-py code).

I looked inside the container object and I was not able to find any information that would be of use for as `'HostIp': '0.0.0.0'` is the remote docker host.

I need an IP or DNS name of the remote machine.

I know that I could start parsing `DOCKER_HOST` myself and "guess" that but this would not really be a reliable way of doing it, especially as there are multiple protocols involved: ssh:// and tcp:// at least.

I guess it should be an API based way of getting this information.

PS. We would assume that the docker host does not have firewall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: Many of the answers to that question seem relevant.  In general, since a container's network stack is isolated from the host's _by design_, this isn't something the container gets to know; it is essentially the same question as "my home router assigned my laptop an IP address of 192.168.1.2/24 but what's my _real_ external IP address"?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not saying that the container itself needs to know but docker server/connection should be able to report it. My question is about docker-py not reporting where the the port-binding occured... so if you started a container using docker-py you have no knowledge on how to connect to it using the the public interface.... not without doing some guessing.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I ended up creating a bug on https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/2254 as I failed to find that information with the library.

Answer (score -1):

The best method is probably to use a website like wtfismyip.com.
You can use

```
curl wtfismyip.com
```

to print it in terminal, and can then extract the public ip from the output.

Comment: This has nothign to do with the question which is about docker-py API.