# How to access host MySQL server in a Docker container?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, docker-compose

I have a MySQL server on my host machine and I want my docker containers connect to it, instead of create a MySQL container.

In my application configuration file I'm using `localhost`, as I used to do before using Docker, but the connection is being refused.

I'm using docker-compose and here is my `.yml`:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
    php:
        build: 
            context: './dockerfiles/php/'
            args:
                PHP_VERSION: ${PHP_VERSION}
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
        container_name: acadbase_php

    apache:
        build:
            context: './dockerfiles/apache/'
            args:
                APACHE_VERSION: ${APACHE_VERSION}
        depends_on:
            - php
        networks:
            - frontend
            - backend
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ${PROJECT_ROOT}/:/var/www/html/
        container_name: acadbase_apache

networks:
    frontend:
    backend:

volumes:
    data:
```

My `./dockerfiles/php/Dockerfile`:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=""
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION:+${PHP_VERSION}-}fpm-alpine

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade; \
    apk add libxml2-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli soap mbstring xml pdo_mysql
```

My  `./dockerfiles/apache/Dockerfile`:

```
ARG APACHE_VERSION=""
FROM httpd:${APACHE_VERSION:+${APACHE_VERSION}-}alpine

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade; \
    apk add vim;

COPY acadbase.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/acadbase.conf
RUN echo "Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/acadbase.conf" \
    >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

My `.env`:

```
PHP_VERSION=7.1
APACHE_VERSION=2.4
PROJECT_ROOT=.
```

Comment: you are not doing any port mapping in your docker-compose.yaml from   hostport:containerport    this gives processes inside the container access to ports visible on the host

Comment: @ScottStensland but if I do it, what IP should I use together with the created port in my application to do this conection?

Comment: none ... look at your current apache port setting for  "8080:80"  which just maps host port 8080 into container port 80 ... do similar for your sql port

Comment: @ScottStensland I have this string in my application config file: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=admin'. If I only create a new port connection "3306:3307" I'll can not use "localhost" as host, because it points to the container, not to the host machine. And I couldn't even create a port like that, because when I do it I'm getting ```Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @StrahinjaTasic and @AvinashReddy said, I need to use the IP of my host machine, but it was not working only because I needed to do more things in my MySQL local server.

1- I needed to allow the database user connects from the container IP (or from everywhere) instead of only from localhost.

```sql
# use the correct IP if it is not for local development
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '[user]'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

For MySQL `GRANT` command details see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

2- I needed to change MySQL configuration file to let it listen not only localhost, but also the container IP (or everywhere).

In my case, the configuration file is `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf`.

```
# use the correct IP if it is not for local development
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

After that I put the IP of my host machine and my database user credentials in my application configuration file and it worked!

P.S.: To get the container IP see [How to get a Docker container's IP address from the host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157721/how-to-get-a-docker-containers-ip-address-from-the-host)

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to the host from the container with the domain - host.docker.internal, which holds the host's internal ip.

Comment: I got this exception: PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container

Comment: I saw this topic and I got the host IP already, the problem is when I use it I'm receivng a 504 timeout

Answer (score 0):

You were using loopback address of the host machine. Instead use the inet(ip address) of the network interface. "eth0" should be your interface name.

Comment: I got this exception: PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve

Comment: did you use the ip or hostname? Try with IP. DNS name cannot be resolved inside the container

Comment: I tried with the IP I got from ```/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'``` but now I'm getting a 504 timeout

Answer (score 0):

localhost cant be resolved from container. You should use IP address of local machine (example: 192.168.1.10) which should be accessable from container. Also why you don't just add MySQL container to your .yml file and add volume link to your local directory so data persists. I can leave you example of this if you want :)

Good luck.

Comment: I'm not able to use IP address of local machine, it's not working. And I know how to work with MySQL in a container, but here we have a production database server and so I want to use my local MySQL server in my local docker environment to help me to use in production only changing the IP.