# Is there any way to get the EC2 instance ip from docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a python program which is running inside the docker container on Amazon EC2 instance.
I want to fetch the EC2 instance private IP inside my python program (which is running inside the docker container) without using `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4` this URL.
It is easy to get the private IP of the machine using python's `socket` library,
like

```
socker.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

but it doesn't give the EC2 instance's IP. Is anyone having any idea how to do it?

Comment: Suggesting you to remove the actual IP of the machine to convey the meaning but not cause security issues

Answer (score 2):

It won't be possible to get host IP from a container if you are using overlay network or external.  It is possible to get IP of the EC2 instance from the host by running
`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`

Pass this as an environment variable when you start the container.  For eg. `docker run -e HOSTIP=$(http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)`

or in your compose file:

```
environment:
  - HOSTIP=${HOSTIP:-`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`}
```

Answer (score 0):

To know the IP of the host machine you can do the below inside the docker container.

```sh
/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
```

In python, you can probably use `subprocess` module to get the result.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Similar question: [How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container)