# Docker-compose: connect from Docker container to linux host

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-compose

In "naked" Docker, I can use `--network=host` to make the host reachable from the container through the `docker0` interface at `127.0.0.1`, or I can reach the host at `172.17.0.1`.

Ostensibly `docker-compose` supports the host networking driver through `network_mode: host`. Unfortunately, this prevents me from using exposed ports. Containers created using `docker-compose` don't live on the `docker0` interface, and hence can reach the host at some IP address like `172.18.0.1` or `172.19.0.1`, decided at startup.

Even once I know that address, it doesn't seem to be reachable from the container.

How can I connect from the container to the host?

Comment: There are a couple of workarounds to this described in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=1) and [How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container).  The default gateway in the container's network will be the host.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?