# docker-compose `host-gateway` on Linux cannot connect to RPC (v20.10.1)

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, localhost

With the advent of Docker `20.10`, `host-gateway` is supposed to be available on Linux platforms (as detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541732/7913944) wonderful answer). As such, it should be possible to create a `docker-compose` script which is platform agnostic. (I myself am on Debian.)

Here are some links to some questions and answers that were helpful in getting me this far: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999693/docker-compose-connect-from-docker-container-to-linux-host), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48546124/what-is-linux-equivalent-of-host-docker-internal), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541732/7913944) (along with some of the other answers and comments)

I'm trying to create a script for running [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/docs/), which involves having `ipfs` and `postgres` running inside a Docker container, and connecting to an instance of a blockchain outside of Docker (on port 8545). Here is the script:

```
 version: '3'
services:
  graph-node:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    image: graphprotocol/graph-node
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '8001:8001'
      - '8020:8020'
      - '8030:8030'
      - '8040:8040'
    depends_on:
      - ipfs
      - postgres
    environment:
      postgres_host: postgres
      postgres_user: graph-node
      postgres_pass: let-me-in
      postgres_db: graph-node
      ipfs: 'ipfs:5001'
      ethereum: 'localhost:http://host.docker.internal:8545'
      RUST_LOG: info
  ipfs:
    image: ipfs/go-ipfs:v0.4.23
    ports:
      - '5001:5001'
    volumes:
      - ./data/ipfs:/data/ipfs
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    command: ["postgres", "-cshared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements"]
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: graph-node
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: let-me-in
      POSTGRES_DB: graph-node
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Docker starts just fine, and the instances of `ipfs`, `postgres`, and the `graph-node` all start up fine, but then the `graph-node`'s RPC calls (to the blockchain) all fail with errors similar to the following:

```
WARN Trying again after eth_getBlockByNumber(0, false) RPC call failed (attempt #18) with result Err(Transport error: Error(Connect, Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }))
```

Am I using `extra-hosts` wrong? What might I be able to do to make this script work both on my Linux machine, but also for Mac and Windows users?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure out a solution for that problem? I have the same issue..

Comment: @Twixx unfortunately not

Comment: I am running into this issue now. it just randomly started happening. When I ssh into the graph-node docker, I can ping into the host no problem, but as soon as I add the port 8545 to connect to chain I get connection refused. I am using --hostname 0.0.0.0 option on the hardhat node, so not sure what can be going on here....

Comment: hmm and now it randomly works... seems like it was this --hostname 0.0.0.0 option on the hardhat node that fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that the application running on your host is bound to a different interface than the one used by Docker.

You can check with `netstat`:

```
$ netstat -pan | grep 8545
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8545          :::*                    LISTEN      496150/java
```

If it is listening on `127.0.0.1`, like in this example, this means it can only be accessed via the loopback interface.

The solution is to find out what IP address host-gateway points to and make sure the service binds to that IP address instead of 127.0.0.1.

If it's no problem when the service is available on all interfaces (including for example your wifi network), you can bind to `0.0.0.0` to make it available on all interfaces.

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well and I see the following on the host when I run the `netstat` command: `tcp6       0      0 :::8545                 :::*                    LISTEN      23703/geth`.

Comment: This means your service is already listening on all interfaces (`::` is the IPv6-compatible way of writing `0.0.0.0`), so you don't have the problem for which my answer is the solution. I know of another possible problem that might match the same symptoms, though - I'll add a second answer about that.

Answer (score 2):

If the host system is Linux, it is possible that your host firewall rules are being applied to communication between your containers. You can check whether that is the case with `sysctl`, it would return `1` for the following settings:

```
$ sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables
1
$ sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables
1
$ sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
```

You can fix this behavior by setting these values to '0':

```
$ sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
$ sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
$ sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
```

Comment: Yup, all of those values were `1`. I changed them all to `0` but still when I run a container and then `exec -it /bin/bash` into it, I can't connect to the host on port 8545: `root@localhost:~/code/metis/ops# docker exec -it ops_l2geth-mainnet_1 /bin/sh
/ # geth attach http://host.docker.internal:8545
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post "http://host.docker.internal:8545": context deadline exceeded`. However, if I manually run `ufw allow 8545` then the above `geth attach` command works. I'm trying to figure out how to enable just local containers access to 8545

Comment: Hmm, I thought ufw would use iptables under the hood. Would be interested to hear how this fits together when you figure it out!