# --extra-index-url is not working in docker file

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, pypiserver

I have setup local pypiserver using following docker-compose.yml and it is working when i use it directly like

`pip install -r requirements.txt --extra-index-url http://127.0.0.1:8082`

However, When I try to use same command in Dockerfile, it is not working. Files I have created following files:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ARG PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN echo "${PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL}"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt $PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL
COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8082/simple/
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8800:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

When I try to run `docker-compose up`
I am getting following errors:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, http://127.0.0.1:8082/simple/
Collecting http://127.0.0.1:8082/simple/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7407596df0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7407596b20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f74089dcf70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f74089dca60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f74089dcdf0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /simple/
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8082): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f74089dcac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt $PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is any configuration missing in this code?

Comment: pypi server is cofigured with docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

127.0.0.1 will resolve to the container itself inside the container. You have to specify the IP address of the host as seen from the container.

See e.g. [How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container) for how to obtain this information.

Comment: Sorry @tripleee, I forgot to mentioned that I have configured local pypiserver with docker. After changing IP address it still gives same error.

Comment: Changed how? Configured where? The simplest explanation is that you didn't manage to figure out the correct IP address still.

Comment: tripleee, I am running these projects in ubuntu virtualbox.  I have used following process to get IP address.https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-findip.html.en . I guess ip address is correct.

Comment: No, that address won't work for a local Docker container. You'll have to query Docker to find the IP address of your Docker host. I updated the answer with a link.