# Node using require('os').networkInterfaces() gives 172 local ip address instead of 192, but only 192 appears to work

Tags: node.js, ip-address

EDIT: This is because I'm running my application in a docker container. I'm not sure what the best thing to do here is – I could delete the question, but if others are as slow as I am, then I this might lead them to the real question which is here:

[How to get the IP address of the docker host from inside a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container)

I'm hoping to get the local IP address of the computer my node application is running on. Using the following:

```
const nets = require('os').networkInterfaces();
console.log('NETS', nets);
```

I get this output:

```
{
lo: [
 {
   address: '127.0.0.1',
   netmask: '255.0.0.0',
   family: 'IPv4',
   mac: '00:00:00:00:00:00',
   internal: true,
   cidr: '127.0.0.1/8'
 }
],
eth0: [
 {
   address: '172.19.0.7',
   netmask: '255.255.0.0',
   family: 'IPv4',
   mac: '02:42:ac:13:00:07',
   internal: false,
   cidr: '172.19.0.7/16'
 }
]
```

}

I understand that addresses beginning with 172 are local network addresses like those beginning with 192, but if I put that 172 address into a browser nothing happens at all.

If I check my network settings, it says my local address is of the typical `192.168.1.xx` sort, and putting that ip in a browser does access my local server.

I'm running this on mac os x.

My end goal is really to get the 192 address if I can, which I thought the networkInterfaces() function would allow me to do. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

Michael

Comment: Are you running your app in Docker? I'm wondering if you have a virtual interface that's giving you the 172 address.

Comment: Oh my god I'm such an idiot. Of course that's the problem. I'll edit my question immediately

Comment: Happens to the best of us!