# A non-root user access denied to dockerized MariaDB (root works)

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I have created a user xyz with credentials identical to the root's, using the latest mariadb docker image:

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
+-------------+-----------+
| User        | Host      |
+-------------+-----------+
| root        | %         |
| xyz         | 127.0.0.1 |
| healthcheck | 127.0.0.1 |
| healthcheck | ::1       |
| xyz         | localhost |
| healthcheck | localhost |
| mariadb.sys | localhost |
| root        | localhost |
+-------------+-----------+
```

and

```
mysql> show grants for xyz@'127.0.0.1';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for xyz@127.0.0.1                                                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `xyz`@`127.0.0.1` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*something'                     |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `somedatabase`.* TO `xyz`@`127.0.0.1`                                                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, I can log in as a root, but not as xyz:

```
bash> mysql -uroot -h 127.0.0.1 -P3308 -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 19
....

bash> mysql -uxyz -h 127.0.0.1 -P3308 -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xyz'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

Any idea what might be going on? How can investigate this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from the host through an exposed port or from within the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

The error compared to the grants tells you the problem:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xyz'@'172.17.0.1' (using password: YES)
```

```
| xyz         | 127.0.0.1 |
```

The container sees you from connectin from `172.17.0.1` (most likely the host machine), but your privileges only allow connection from `127.0.0.1`.

### Solution

The simplest solution would be to allow the user `xyz` to connect from anywhwere with the same `%` as the host as `root` has, but it has some security implications.

If you do that and don't want any connections from outside of the host machine, please make sure that container port is only exposed *on the host machine*, not outside.

That means that if you run your container with a command something like this:

```
docker run -p 3308:3308 mariadb:latest
```

you are exposing it outwards too. Make sure to do it like this instead:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3308:3308 mariadb:latest
```

Comment: Thank you Teemu, this works indeed.  The root works because of  the % thing. It is a bit puzzling though - how are we to know what is the IP that the container will be using?

Comment: It's to do with how docker networking works internally, but take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944631/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container if you want to find out the host IP programmatically. Or if you run both your application and the DB in containers, you can set up hostnames for them (docker compose does this nicely automatically) and set the permissions to allow those hostnames.

Comment: Thank you Teemu this was really helpful. (I am trying to use the official MariaDB image, so the internal spec is not up to me)