# how to get ip address of localhost

Tags: linux, bash, ip-address

I need an ip address of a local host in order to use it in an url string. I want to connect to other computer by using port forwarding. The connecting will be written in a bash script.

So, is there a way to generically parse an ip address of a localhost?

Comment: Any suggestions? Perhaps I'm not clear enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I get the primary IP address of the local machine on Linux and OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x)

Comment: Why from **localhost** only you want
use any command/way to find IPaddress of machine out of so many available!!!!

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42173/ip-of-localhost

Comment: Thank you, so it's this: ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Translated into an IP address, commonly a localhost is always designated as `127.0.0.1`. So generally, you can consider the loop back address same for every machine.

To get address other than `127.0.0.1` you may use the following bash command:
`hostname -i`.

Comment: that address didn't work for me

Comment: Probably lowercase i in parameters `hostname -i`.

Comment: uuu,this one is great! so short!

Comment: this should be marked as an answer, since it is shorter then mine.

Comment: a agree, you even answered first.

Answer (score 1):

One of many solutions:

```
localhost_ip_address=`ping -c 1 localhost | head -n 1 | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1`
```

Comment: or you can run in terminal only this: `ping -c 1 localhost | head -n 1 | cut -d'(' -f2 | cut -d')' -f1`