# How to allow other devices to visit server created by grunt-contrib-connect?

Tags: grunt-contrib-connect

I have the following options for grunt-contrib-connect. I am able to run connect fine on my own desktop.

How should I allow other devices (other pcs, tablets or phones) to access my desktop?

I've tried xip.io but I can't seem to get it to work.

Help is much appreciated!

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: '*',
    base: 'public',
    livereload: 35729,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your hostname to '0.0.0.0' as stated in the inline comment so it should now be:

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    hostname: '0.0.0.0',
    base: 'public',
    livereload: 35729,
  },
}
```

Also a handy way to extract your local ip address from your connected network to be used with xip:

[How to I get the primary IP address of the local machine on Linux and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x)

So your xip.io URL that you will load on your mobile devices would be for example:

`192.168.1.xxx.xip.io:9000` where x is the unique integer binded to your host device.

Comment: Doh! The answer was right infront of my eyes! Thanks @Rish!