# How to find primary ip address on my linux machine?

Tags: linux, networking, ip-address

I heard that there are types of ip addresses like primary address etc. and tried to get the ip address using the below command

```
ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1'
```

and got the result as below

> ```
> 192.168.122.1
> 192.168.168.1
> 172.16.142.1
> 192.168.1.102
> ```

so from the above can someone answer which my primary address is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I get the primary IP address of the local machine on Linux and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x) You should also state the programming language you are working with. You will get better results.

Answer (score 2):

When a machine has different IP addresses, it is impossible to define the primary IP from a network only point of view. But a machine normaly has a name that can be obtained by the command `uname -n`, or by the POSIX function `uname`. Once you have that name, you can find the IP address corresponding to it by the `getent` command or the `gethostbyname` function: what is called the primary IP address is the first address returned.

So here you could use:

```
getent hosts $(uname -n) | head -1 | cut -f 1 -w
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such things as "primary address" or "primary device". You have multiple ip addresses related to multiple networt devices.

You could find out what devices allows you to access to the internet and finds its local ip.

To do that, issue the command `route`. It will output something like

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Now all you need is to use the device on the line `default` and use it in this command:

```
ifconfig <DEVICENAME> | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

Primary address depends on your usage, there is nothing as such at the network level. If you use one IP to access your server usually, you may call it primary and the network devices won't know the difference.