# Automatically set host IP as an environment property in docker

Tags: docker, kitematic

I am in a corporate dhcp network and the ip changes frequently. While running one of the docker containers in my laptop, i have to pass the local ip of my machine for allowing a call back to a different application.

I am now running the container with -e MYHOST=x.x.x.x. But when IP changes, i have to lookup the ip manually and edit this property and restart my container.

I use Kitematic for launching. Is there a way it can be configured to automatically pickup the hostIP. Something like -e MYHOST=${hostIP}

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think you have to use the `--network=host` option to `docker-run`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you just need a command providing you the ip address on your operating system.

Then you can do

```
docker run -e MYHOST=$(<ip-command>) your-image
```

For example on Linux you could do

```
docker run -e MYHOST=$(hostname -i) your-image
```

Check for more options, including MacOS, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x).