# I am running a redis(docker image) on local nodejs application

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

i'm trying to use redis connection on local node js application but it throwing an error ---

events.js:183
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)

[image]

[image]

[image: running none docker image]

[image: running docker image]

Comment: your question is not clear... you need to provide more details, like the Dockerfile used for redis and node, the commands you are trying to run, how you started the docker container, etc.

Comment: Are you even exposing the port?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are running node inside a Docker container. This node process is trying to reach redis instance running at localhost.

This does not work, because container (node) has its own network stack, and 127.0.0.1 does not point to the host.

In this case you'd need to either

1. Run redis in its own container (and use e.g. docker-compose) OR
2. Change the Node connection host for redis from localhost (or 127.0.0.1) to your host IP address. See [How to get the primary IP address of the local machine on Linux and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x) for finding IP address

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the wrong port. As the `docker ps` command says, the port where `redis` is listening is `32768`. Connecting to that port should solve your issue.

See [the official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) (in particular the flag `-p`) for more information about customizing port listening.

Comment: var redis = require("redis"),
  redis_client = redis.createClient("redis://127.0.0.1:32768");
-------------------------------------------------
Thanks this did the work done!

Comment: If this was the correct answer, then mark it as the solution please!

Answer (score 0):

You can also resolve this error by redoing your Docker container, just add the "-p 6379: 6379" flag. Example (Redis with persistent date):

> docker run --name some-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis redis-server
> --appendonly yes