# if then else in bash not matching string

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script in my .bash_profile and comparing an ip address to assign a variable.  I don't know much about shell scripting, I've been doing google searches to get the right syntax so forgive me if its something simple.  This is the script and the response:

```
ipaddr=`hostname -I`
prodip=172.24.79.95
echo "ipaddr is "$ipaddr
echo "prodip is "$prodip
if [ "$ipaddr" == "$prodip" ];
then
   echo "in then"
   desturl="s3://pr-adip-air-8753-us-east-1"
else
   echo "in else"
   desturl="s3://dv-adip-prod-clone-8337-us-west-2"
fi

echo "desturl is "$desturl
```

after running it

```
ipaddr is 172.24.79.95
prodip is 172.24.79.95
in else
desturl is s3://dv-adip-prod-clone-8337-us-west-2
```

Comment: Have a look [How to get the primary IP address of the local machine on Linux and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322667/1765658)

Comment: fwiw ... I manually set `ipaddr` and `prodip` to `172.24.79.95` and your code works for me (ie, prints 'in then'); try adding `typeset -p ipaddr prodip` to see if there are any unwanted/non-visible characters in the variables (I'm wondering if `hostname -I` is returning something in addition to the single ip address)

Comment: fwiw ... when I run `hostname -I` on my systems (cygwin, ubuntu 22.04) I receive multiple ip addresses *plus* a trailing single space; if your `hostname -I` is adding a trailing space then that would explain the `in else` output; once you get your code working you may want to revisit the logic to handle the case of `hostname -I` returning multiple ips

Comment: What does the command `file your_script.sh` produce? is that "ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators"?

Comment: it gives me this, ASCII text, with very long lines

Comment: @markp-fuso, I added that line and get this, it appears there is an extra space, declare -- ipaddr="172.24.79.95 "
declare -- prodip="172.24.79.95"

Comment: Is there an equivalent of chomp in shell scripting?

Comment: @JamesFinnegan: perl `chomp` only removes a newline (or more exactly the record separator `$/` which is _usually_ newline); it doesn't remove space or tab. shell command substitution `$(..)` or `\`..\`` also removes trailing newline -- but not CR if present, and not space or tab.You could wordsplit (on IFS which normally includes space and tab) with something like `read firstip discard < <(hostname -I)`

Comment: Maybe try this to get rid of new line after `hostname -I` runs. Code to remove `ipaddr=\`echo $ipaddr|tr -d '\n'\``

Comment: there are a handful of options under the heading of [parameter substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for removing unwanted characters, eg: `ip="${ip// }"` or `ip="${ip// /}"` (this is a bit overkill as it will remove *all* spaces regardless of where located in string)

Comment: The syntax is fine, except the semicolon at the end of the `if` line (not sure whether it is allowed, but it is certainly not needed) . I would for sure remove it. Aside from this, I wouldn't print the addresses with `echo`, but for debugging use i.e. `xxdump <<<$ipaddr` instead.

Comment: CORRECTION: I means `xxd`, not `xxdump`.

Comment: `declare -p ipaddr prodip` is a more effective way to print a definition of your two variables with hidden and nonprintable characters visibly shown.

Comment: you have `==` instead of `=` in your test.

Comment: also, easier debugging with: `echo "ipaddr is '$ipaddr'"` so you see exactly what is in the var.