# PHP gethostbyname returns hostname instead of IP address

Tags: php, gethostbyname

I am checking current hosting IP of websites using

```
$ip = gethostbyname('domainname.com');
```

It Returns IP address of websites working well but for some domains it returns back the domain name

```
$ip = gethostbyname('domainname.com');
```

Returns:

> domianname.com

Comment: It returns IP address bro. Whats problem ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php -> `Returns the IPv4 address or a string containing the unmodified hostname on failure.` . if you want to get server ip, try `$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800927/how-to-identify-server-ip-address-in-php

Comment: problem solved by mistakenly i forget to use trime()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php):

> Returns the IPv4 address or a string containing the unmodified hostname on failure.

So you are on a failure situation.