# Getting IP Address current server

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I used **symfony 1.4** to create my application.

I'd like to get the IP adress of the current server to put it within soap request

So, how can i get the IP address of the current server?

Comment: This is not a Symfony related question, please check this answers about getting the server IP on PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800927/how-to-identify-server-ip-address-in-php

Comment: It depends if they need to get the IP address using the framework. It is not recommanded to use globals for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most situations, using `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` will work.  If that doesn't work you can try `$ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());`

Answer (score 1):

Premise of the following method: your domain name has only one IP resolution

Using PHP:

```
gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
```

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`will generally return your domain name (server_name / ServerName is configured in Nginx / Apache server), and then use `gethostbyname()`.

---

About `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`, it often return a LAN IP address (I only have one server, one domain name, no reverse proxy; cloud server).

---

About `gethostname()`
In the test, it returns the name of the server (host name, not the domain name you use), and then uses `gethostbyname()`, will return a LAN IP.

---

More can be used `https://checkip.amazonaws.com/` Get the current IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the $request object and it is a sfWebRequest (typical request from a browser) you can use:

```
$request->getPathInfoArray()['SERVER_ADDR']
```