# How to get the server IP with Laravel

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel, I can get the client IP with `request()->ip()`.

Is there a **Laravel built-in way** to get the server IP? Or is it something "impossible" (same problem as `SERVER_ADDR`reliability)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify server IP address in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800927/how-to-identify-server-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: @patricus Thanks. My question was about a laravel built-in way. I did not tagged it `php` for that reason. That's why I think it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The problem is that laravel is built on top of PHP. If there is no reliable way in PHP, there won't be a reliable way in laravel. But, as has been answered, there is a laravel way of accessing the $_SERVER superglobal, but as you mentioned in your question, still not reliable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use request object:

```
request()->server('SERVER_ADDR');
```

Or you can use standard PHP way:

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 2):

`Request::server('SERVER_ADDR')`  :)

URL Reference: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html

Comment: Thanks. It returns the client IP, I'm looking for server IP

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; for server ip
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; for server port
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want client IP, but server IP

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, you can only get the server IP using

> $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR']

if it is  LINUX, use :

> $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

```
/** Server IP Check **/
if(!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']){ $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR']; }

/** Get Server IP **/
!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']))?$_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR']:$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way on the server.

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

But you can not access `SERVER_ADDR` index locally. It will through `Undefined index: SERVER_ADDR` error. In my case, I face this error.

A better solution would be using variable from **.env** file which will work locally and server as well.

Defined a variable in `.env` file like this. You can give any name you want.

```
SERVER_ADDR = 127.0.0.1
```

Note: Please note `SERVER_ADDR` value should be  `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to get the server address value.

Now you can access this variable like this:

```
env('SERVER_ADDR');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

and if you are hosting locally, **::1** could be shown or your hosting ip address!