# Laravel - Get client IP address - Getting always 127.0.0.1 result

Tags: laravel, ip, guzzle

I'm unable to get the IP address of the client which I need to determine his current location.

I've used request->ip(), $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and I always get a 127.0.0.1 result which is not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First things first: Is this a local installation? Or is it served publicly?

Comment: @maiorano84 It is a local installation, I'm using Laragon

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira is your url something like localhost, 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Then that's your problem. You're not going to get a remote address, because the request isn't coming in remotely. You're either going to get a localhost or network IP. Once you throw it up onto a publicly accessible server outside of your network, then you'll start seeing remote public IPs.

Comment: Can NGROK solve it? EDIT - It can't, I get ::1 in response

Comment: That's the IPv6 way of saying "localhost".

Comment: Your method has no problem. When the project is uploaded on the host, everything is correct. In local mode, it is usually 127.0.0.1 or 1 ::

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes your clients use your application through a proxy, so you should not depend on $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

Check out this link (*with a little concern on securities*):
[How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

`request->ip()` will give you client IP. You're getting `127.0.0.1` in because you're trying to access your local project from the same machine.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the client IP not the server IP.

Comment: You're right. I've answered [`SERVER_ADDR` related question recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258208/how-to-get-the-server-ip-with-laravel/41258486#41258486), so I automatically read it as `SERVER_ADDR` ) Thanks, I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to fix it. But beware that you have to change it before going production!!

Read this part: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies

And now just add this:

```
class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $proxies = '*';
```

Now request()->ip() gives you the correct ip

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function get_ip() {
    $keys = array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR');

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is client IP address this code(`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) applied online project then it will work successfully . it will try..