# How to register a middleware to all routes with no exceptions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to apply a middleware to any request to my server

this middleware should check for whitelisted Ips

registering the middleware to each single route is not a perfect solution

what if he navigated to non-implemented route like 404 Page

implemented routes

```
/r1

/r2

/r3
```

if he navigated to /4 for example - it will navigate to 404 page , but also in this case - I want to use the middleware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#global-middleware

There is dedicated section about this

> Global Middleware
>
> If you want a middleware to run during every HTTP request to your application, list the middleware class in the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class.

Comment: worked thank , I gonna accept your answer after 7 minutes

Comment: may I ask another question ?

Comment: Yes you can ask any amount of question in stackoverflow. Click on `Ask Question`

Comment: but it is not a big question , $request->getClientIp() always return 127.0.0.1 instead of the client public ip address

Comment: did you try just `\Request::ip();` ? or `$request->ip()` ?

Comment: both returning `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I think this is my issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286310/laravel-get-client-ip-address-getting-always-127-0-0-1-result